# How to compile an avro schema using avro-python with multiple .avsc files?

Tags: python, maven, apache-kafka, avro

I can't parse my .avsc because it is not self contained.

```
schema = avro.schema.parse(open("XXX.avsc", "rb").read())
```

throws

raise SchemaParseException(fail_msg)
avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Type property "[u'null', u'x.y']" not a valid Avro schema: Union item must be a valid Avro schema: Could not make an Avro Schema object from x.y.

I have a bunch of .avsc files which contain all the definitions, including x.y

The way to handle this in maven is to list schemas in a pom.xml in the right order. How do I accomplish this using python avro?

Thanks!

Edit: There was a pom.xml available, which I "package"d using maven. Now I have a .jar, and .class files. How do I use this into the python avro parser, instead of the XXX.avsc?

Comment: Hi maverik, its been a long time you asked this question, can I know that did you got the answer to this question i.e. comparing one avro schema with another? If so could you please help me with that.

Comment: AFAIK it can't be done in Python using Apache APIs. There's an open JIRA ticket somewhere calling this out as a bug. We used java

Comment: Thank you maverik, can I know the process that you followed using java, If possible can I get the code of what you have done or link to the code for my reference, since it could help me a lot. I have bee searching for this from one month but no luck.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Consuming kafka packets and deserializing them are two distinct steps. Have you looked up the javadocs/kafka API? It will take time for me to remove the proprietary bits from my code but we just referenced: https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html for the avro deserializer bit look up https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html (Ignore the "Getting started - Python" section. Didn't work as advertised for me)

Comment: "Need to validate AVRO file with structure (schema-i.e. field, data type, size etc.)." This is what I'm exactly looking for. I have an avro file from the customer and a schema in separate notepad, all I need to do is validate AVRO file with structure.
My questions are...
1) what is avro schema validation?
2) How exactly i need to do it?
Please help me to achieve this.